# Best approach to add an item to a databound Listbox using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm facing a problem in my WPF project at the moment. At this moment I have a Viewmodel which has a Manager (to communicate with the repo).

```
internal class TicketViewModel
{
    private TicketManager mgr;

    public IEnumerable<Ticket> List { get; set; }


    public TicketViewModel()
    {
        mgr = new TicketManager();
        List = mgr.GetTickets();

    }

}
```

I've managed to bind this list to the Listbox in my MainWindow. The next step is that I need to add an extra ticket to the list and also pass this through the manager. The problem is I need two parameters from some Controls in the MainWindow. From MVVM perspective I need to use bound Commands on e.g. a Button to communicate with the viewmodel as my viewmodel can't/may not access controls from the window. Is using parameterized Commands the way to go here?

The next problem is that the Listbox won't update I guess. This is the code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listboxTix" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Bisque" Background="Beige" BorderThickness="2">
                <StackPanel Width="250">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TicketNumber}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding State}" />
            </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I found that using a CompareableCollection is the way to go here, but then I still have to read all the Tickets again after adding a new Ticket.

Thanks in advance,
Hicy

Comment: Do you mean you need to have a control like button which will fill the list with new ticket?

Comment: How are getting inputs for new tickets?

Comment: I think you need to bind it to `observablecollection` rather than `Ienumerable`

Comment: @kyle I have 2 Textboxes and a Button. The button needs to add the content from the textboxes into a new Ticket and the list should be updated auto. The manager has the method: AddTicket(int,string)

Answer (score 3):

okay here is the code.

Lets say you have three textboxes on MainWindow(since you have three Textblocks.) so Your **MainWindow.xaml** looks like

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>--set's your viewModel
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="250*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="listboxTix" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Bisque" Background="Beige" BorderThickness="2">
                    <StackPanel Width="250">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TicketNumber}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding State}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="TicketNumber" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Text}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Text" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=State}" />
    <TextBox x:Name="State" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=TicketNumber}" />
    <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding Path=MainCommand}"  Grid.Row="2"/>

</Grid>
```

and I am assuming that you have some class called class **Ticket** which contain these three members

```
Class Ticket
{
    public int TicketNumber { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Now in class **TicketManager** we fill it with some dummy data

```
 class TicketManager
{
    ObservableCollection<Ticket> tl = new ObservableCollection<Ticket>();
    internal ObservableCollection<Ticket> GetTickets()
    {
        tl.Add(new Ticket() { State = "State1", Text = "Text1", TicketNumber = 1 });
        tl.Add(new Ticket() { State = "State2", Text = "Text2", TicketNumber = 2 });
        tl.Add(new Ticket() { State = "State3", Text = "Text3", TicketNumber = 3 });

        return tl;
    }

}
```

and in your Mainwindow ViewModel lets call it **MyViewModel.cs** we add

```
class MyViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TicketManager mgr;
    public ObservableCollection<Ticket> List { get; set; }

    private string text;
    private string state;
    private int ticketNumber;

    private readonly DelegateCommand<object> MyButtonCommand;
    public Class1()
    {
        mgr = new TicketManager();
        List = mgr.GetTickets();
        MyButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>((s) => { AddListToGrid(text, state, ticketNumber); }, (s) => { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(state); });

    }

    private void AddListToGrid(string text, string state, int ticketNumber)
    {
        List.Add(new Ticket() {Text=text,State=state,TicketNumber=ticketNumber });
    }

    public DelegateCommand<object> MainCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return MyButtonCommand;
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return text;
        }
        set
        {
            text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            MyButtonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public string State
    {
        get
        {
            return state;
        }
        set
        {
            state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("State");
            MyButtonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public int TicketNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return ticketNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            ticketNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TicketNumber");
            MyButtonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

You can Modify the code in anyway you want

This ViewModel implements fewthings which are very important from MVVM point of view

1) [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

2) [WPF Delegate Command](http://www.wpftutorial.net/delegatecommand.html)

P.S:The code is tested and it runs as expected

Answer (score 0):

Don't get hung up on `MVVM` it is simply a separation of data from a view, and models are shared between the two with a majority of the business logic (on a shared component) should be performed on the VM; it is not a religion just a three tiered data system. *IMHO*

If your button needs to do an operation, have it make a call, most likely in the code behind, to a method on the `VM` which handles the business logic, updates the list with the new item and notifies the manager.

I would bind the list in question to an `ObservableCollection` which can notify upon insert/delete of an item.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have some questions. Is it a clean way to call List = mgr.getTickets() after I added a ticket to the manager? How can I notify the manager in the code behind? The only code in the code behind atm is declaring the datacontext

Comment: @Hicy yes that is how I do it. See my blog article [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding.](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017) for an example.

Comment: @Hicy If the code behind has the manager on a data context (I usually keep in on a property as well for easier access) simply call a method on the VM which will do the operations logic in the code behind.

Comment: This is the only code in my codebehind: Datacontext = new TicketViewModel();
So I just can keep a property viewmodel in my codebehind? Is the use of commands still nec here?

Comment: @Hicy one can add anything one wants. Just remember Xaml is ultimately compiled into a 'code-behind' which subsequently joined with the code-behind written on the object. Everything, and I mean everything in Xaml can be done in code behind; so don't get hung up on what is in code-behind and what is not. Just add methods as needed. Remember place business logic on the VM and call it from the view's code-behind. That separates business logic from being in the view and leads to better development/maintenance. MVVM us simply is a three tiered data system. Nothing more, nothing less. HTH